# Stata non-obvious type mismatch error r(109)?

Tags: analytics, stata

When calculating a date, a non-obvious error appears on line 103:

```
collapse (mean)  welfare runcs profit import_profit runcarbon runemissions runleakage averagepricerun averagefirms averagerate marketsize
```

I use stata 13

[Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ceXEE-WhYfBVKD7_fnIE0FVQ7qJortF6/view?usp=sharing)

```
clear all
set more off

global dirpath =  "C:\Users\kukiman\Documents\stata\code_and_data"

capture mkdir "$dirpath\tables"
capture mkdir "$dirpath\figures"
capture mkdir "$dirpath\figures\market_summary"
capture mkdir "$dirpath\figures\market_welfare_compare"
capture mkdir "$dirpath\figures\panel_figures"
capture mkdir "$dirpath\figures\synthesis"
capture mkdir "$dirpath\figures\temp_files"

*ssc install dm40
global numfirms = 3

global prices "5.0 10.0 15.0 20.0 25.0 30.0 35.0 40.0 45.0 50.0 55.0 60.0 65.0"
global timeT = 30

if ($numfirms == 3) {
global cities "Cincinnati Detroit Minneapolis Pittsburgh SaltLakeCity Seattle"
}
else if ($numfirms == 4) {
global cities "Cincinnati Denver Detroit KansasCity Minneapolis NewYork Phoenix Pittsburgh SaltLakeCity SanFrancisco Seattle St.Louis"
}
else if ($numfirms == 5) {
global cities "Birmingham Chicago Cincinnati Dallas Denver Detroit Florida KansasCity Minneapolis NewYork Phoenix Pittsburgh SaltLakeCity SanFrancisco Seattle St.Louis"
}
else if ($numfirms == 6) {
global cities "Atlanta Baltimore Birmingham Chicago Cincinnati Dallas Denver Detroit Florida KansasCity LosAngeles Minneapolis NewYork Phoenix Pittsburgh SaltLakeCity SanAntonio SanFrancisco Seattle St.Louis"
}
else {
global cities "Minneapolis"
}

cd $dirpath

clear
set more off

cd  "$dirpath\data\"
gen mechanism = ""
save simulation_data_$numfirms.dta, replace
    
local city $cities
local permit $prices
local mechanism "Auctioning Grandfather Output BTA"

foreach x of local city {
    insheet using "`x'/`x'_Baseline_0.0.csv", clear
    capture destring averagerate
    capture destring runcs
    gen welfare = (runcs + profit + runcarbon)/1000
    gen averagefirms = (1*runonefirm + 2*runtwofirms + 3*runthreefirms + 4*runfourfirms+ 5*runfivefirms + 6*runsixfirms)/$timeT     
    if ("`x'" == "SaltLakeCity" | "`x'" == "Pittsburgh" | "`x'" == "Dallas" | "`x'" == "Denver" | "`x'" == "St.Louis") {
        replace averagepricerun = averagepricerun * $timeT / ($timeT - runnofirms) 
    }   
    
    destring averagerate, replace force
    
    collapse (mean)  welfare runcs profit import_profit runcarbon runemissions runleakage averagepricerun averagefirms averagerate marketsize
    *summarize welfare runcs profit import_profit runcarbon runemissions runleakage averagepricerun averagefirms averagerate marketsize 
    *describe  welfare runcs profit import_profit runcarbon runemissions runleakage averagepricerun averagefirms averagerate marketsize 
    
    rename runcs cs
    rename runcarbon carbonrevenue
    rename runemissions emissions
    rename runleakage leakage
    rename averagepricerun price
    rename averagefirms num_firms
    rename averagerate erate
    gen carbonprice = 0
    
    label var welfare "Domestic Welfare ($ in NPV) cs+carbonrev+profit"
    label var cs "Net Consumer Surplus ($ in NPV)"
    label var profit "Total Profit ($ in NPV)"  
    label var carbonrevenue "Carbon Revenues ($ in NPV)"
    label var emissions "Discounted emissions (tons in NPV)"
    label var leakage "Discounted leakage (tons in NPV)"
    label var price "Average price ($)"
    label var carbonprice "Carbon price ($)"
    label var num_firms "Number of firms in the market"
        
    gen epa_market = "`x'"                                 
    gen mechanism = "Baseline"
    order mechanism
    order epa_market
    
    append using simulation_data_$numfirms.dta
    save simulation_data_$numfirms.dta, replace
    
    
    foreach m of local mechanism {
        foreach t of local permit {
            insheet using "`x'/`x'_`m'_`t'.csv", clear
            capture destring averagerate
            capture destring runcs                  
            gen welfare = (runcs + profit + runcarbon)/1000
            if ("`m'" == "BTA") {
                replace welfare = welfare + `t'*runleakage/1000
            }
            gen averagefirms = (1*runonefirm + 2*runtwofirms + 3*runthreefirms + 4*runfourfirms+ 5*runfivefirms + 6*runsixfirms)/$timeT     
            if ("`x'" == "SaltLakeCity" | "`x'" == "Pittsburgh" | "`x'" == "Dallas" | "`x'" == "Denver" | "`x'" == "St.Louis") {
                replace averagepricerun = averagepricerun * $timeT / ($timeT - runnofirms) 
            }
            
            destring averagerate, replace force
            
            collapse (mean)  welfare runcs profit import_profit runcarbon runemissions runleakage averagepricerun averagefirms averagerate marketsize 
            *summarize welfare runcs profit import_profit runcarbon runemissions runleakage averagepricerun averagefirms averagerate marketsize 
            *describe welfare runcs profit import_profit runcarbon runemissions runleakage averagepricerun averagefirms averagerate marketsize 
            
            rename runcs cs
            rename runcarbon carbonrevenue
            rename runemissions emissions
            rename runleakage leakage
            rename averagepricerun price
            rename averagefirms num_firms           
            rename averagerate erate
            
            gen carbonprice = `t'
    
            label var welfare "Domestic Welfare ($ in NPV) cs+carbonrev+profit"
            label var cs "Net Consumer Surplus ($ in NPV)"
            label var profit "Total Profit ($ in NPV)"  
            label var carbonrevenue "Carbon Revenues ($ in NPV)"
            label var emissions "Discounted emissions (tons in NPV)"
            label var leakage "Discounted leakage (tons in NPV)"
            label var price "Average price ($)"
            label var carbonprice "Carbon price ($)"
            label var num_firms "Number of firms in the market"
        
            gen epa_market = "`x'"                                 
            gen mechanism = "`m'"
            order mechanism
            order epa_market
    
            append using simulation_data_$numfirms.dta
            save simulation_data_$numfirms.dta, replace         
        }
    }     
}


qui do "$dirpath\stata_code\counterfactual_analysis\create_simulation_panel_data.do"
qui do "$dirpath\stata_code\counterfactual_analysis\create_simulation_capacity_data.do"
qui do "$dirpath\stata_code\counterfactual_analysis\create_dynamic_NPV.do"
/* INDIVIDUAL GRAPHS **********************************************************/
qui do "$dirpath\stata_code\counterfactual_analysis\dynamic_graphs_marketlevel.do"
/* MAIN ANALYSIS **************************************************************/
qui do "$dirpath\stata_code\counterfactual_analysis\synthesis.do"
qui do "$dirpath\stata_code\counterfactual_analysis\panel_analysis.do"
qui do "$dirpath\stata_code\counterfactual_analysis\optimal_tax.do"
qui do "$dirpath\stata_code\counterfactual_analysis\abatement.do"
```

UPD1:
Changed in code: `conv2num` to `destring`; `collapse` to `summarize` and `describe`.

The error has changed to:

```
variable erate is str18 in master but float in using data
You could specify append's force option to ignore this string/numeric mismatch.  The using variable would then be treated as if it contained "".
r(106);
```

What is interesting, this error disappears when we delete last 2 lines, but the file is still written anyway. The data estimation is still wrong.

```
append using simulation_data_$numfirms.dtasave
simulation_data_$numfirms.dta, replace
```

Debug info:

The variable changes the data type, I tried changing it `averagerate has all characters numeric; replaced as floar` team, but not yet
[image]

UPD2: Updated the code. Command `averagerate has all characters numeric; replaced as floar` dont work,  but the command `destring averagerate, replace force` helped me. Unfortunately, my data has become more like the right, but still erroneous, compared to the control example
[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for excellent advice about asking a specific, focused question. `conv2num` is an old command (1996) long since superseded by official command `destring`.

Comment: Run a `summarize` and `describe` on the variables you are feeding to `collapse`.

Comment: @NickCox check my updated messages, please)

Comment: I am not suggesting that summarize and describe replace collapse; only that they will show you which variables are causing a problem.

Comment: I have not tried to understand the original code, but it seems evident that it depends on using `collapse`. So, there is one and only one question: why did `collapse` fail? Debugging that depends on looking at the data before the `collapse`.  Your work depends on datasets we cannot see, so the most anyone can do is make debugging suggestions. This is a poor question for SO without a minimal reproducible example. The code is littered with commands that are irrelevant to the problem, such as `rename` commands..

Comment: @NickCox thanks for your help i added debug info